# The number of primitve elements in $GF(s^2)$

Tags: finite-fields

The multiplicative group of any finite field is cyclic, a generator of this group is called a primitive element of the finite field. Is it true that the number of primitive elements in the finite field $GF(s^2)$ is s+1? If it holds, how can I prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiplicative group of $GF(p^n)$ has order $p^n-1$.
An element $a+m\mathbb Z$ of the cyclic group $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ generates the full group iff $a$ and $m$ are relatively prime. Hence there are $\phi(m)$ generators of $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$.
Finally, this shows tha there are $\phi(p^n-1)$ primitive elements in $GF(p^n)$.
For the case $n=2$ we know that $p^2-1=(p+1)(p-1)$, which makes $\Phi(p^2-1)=p+1$ highly unlikely. In fact, this holds for $p=3$ only, I guess.